# Robot Framework, control it there is error in event viewer/application

Tags: process, pycharm, operating-system, robotframework, sikuli

When i test external Windows application with Robot Framework i would control if there is new error in event viewer/application.

there is a way?

Comment: Have not seen any ready made keyword libraries for such but there's multiple python libs that could be easily used to get the logging..

Comment: Hi rasjany, is there a method to use python libs in robot test?

Comment: https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/extending_robot_framework/custom-libraries/python_library  & https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extending-robot-framework